# Motion of Spring in Vacuum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, energy-conservation, spring

If a spring was compressed a little and placed in a perfect vacuum, what would happen? Would it compress and expand as the law of conservation of energy would suggest or would it somehow return to rest? If so, where does the energy go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the vacuum, the oscillating spring wouldn't lose energy to air resistance. But there will still be *internal* resistance leading to a damping of the oscillations over time. Where does the energy go? Into making the spring a bit hotter.

Answer (score 1):

Probably more important than air resistance at dampening the spring's vibrations is the internal friction of the atoms moving in relation to one another. The energy would end up as internal energy within the spring. You can get a sense of this by straightening out a paper clip, then continuosly bending the same section back and forth. You will, at some point, notice the metal has warmed up enough to sense it with bare hands.